# Laravel Middleware page authority

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-middleware

the idea is i want to use middleware for filtering their roles to my `ektp` routes. so only the users that had been logged in can access the `ektp` page, if not it will be redirect it to `home` and give alert "you need to login".

> web.php

```
route::get('/ektp','PagesController@ektp');
```

i tried to add `->middleware(users)` like my login and register route so it will only displaying on a guest. but some how i got an error `Auth guard [users] is not defined.` if i do it like that.
and when i tried to add `protected $guard ='user';` inside `ektp model` it still show me the same error.

```
//register
route::get('/register','AuthController@getRegister')->middleware('guest');
route::any('/register','AuthController@postRegister')->middleware('guest');

//login
route::get('/login','AuthController@getLogin')->middleware('guest');
route::any('/login','AuthController@postLogin')->middleware('guest');
```

**EDIT**

> Authenticate.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate as Middleware;

class Authenticate extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * Get the path the user should be redirected to when they are not authenticated.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return string
     */
    protected function redirectTo($request)
    {
        if (! $request->expectsJson()) {
            return route('home')->with('warning', 'Need to login');
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: this is what the `auth` middleware is for, the user must be authenticated to reach the route

Comment: @lagbox it is different than the normal middleware?

Comment: what is "normal" middleware? ... the `auth` middleware is the middleware that checks if the current user is authenticated or not ; https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/authentication#protecting-routes

Comment: whoa thanks, so i need to create new controller for my ektp, so the other routes other than ektp didnt get locked.

Comment: you dont have to assign middleware via the controller, and if you do you have options to have it applied only to certain methods or excluding certain methods

Comment: what if i want to add the alert? when i use `return redirect()->route('home')->with('warning', 'need to login')` inside the middleware/Authenticate it got errors `"Header may not contain more than a single header, new line detected"`

Comment: i use sweet alert

Comment: add your middleware to your question

Comment: but when i try to click back from my browser after the error, it got `warning` alert

Comment: clicking 'back' loads the page from cache, it does not make a new request to the server

Comment: so, did i need to create a new routes that specificaly returning the same home page but with the alert function?

Comment: the `redirectTo` method returns a string as the path to redirect to, it does not return a redirect. the `route(...)` helper returns a URL which is a string ... the actual redirect is handled in the Exception Handler by default

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show registration page to those users who havenot logged in 
Simple just not use any middleware or put that route in any middleware group

In case you just want to show the ektp page to logged in users do like this

```
Route::get('/ektp','PagesController@ektp')->middleware(['auth']);
```

OR

```
Route::group(['middleware'=>'auth], function(){
  Route::get('/ektp','PagesController@ektp');
  // Others routes for auth middleware
});
```